# Generate random coordinates in different polygons

Tags: python, random, coordinates, polygon

I'm new into Python.
I want to generate random coordinates inside a set of polygons.

To generate random coordinates inside one Polygon I found this code on Stackoverflor, which works:

```
def polygon_random_points (poly, num_points):
    minx, miny, maxx, maxy = poly.bounds 
    while len(points) < num_points:
        random_point = Point([random.uniform(minx, maxx), random.uniform(miny, maxy)])
        if (random_point.within(poly)):
            points.append(random_point)
    return points
```

But now I struggle to achieve a for loop for all of my polygons. They have this data type: geopandas.geoseries.GeoSeries.
[Alle_Polygone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GkG1.png)

I tried this code:

```
for Standorte in Alle_Polygone:
    def Zufallskoordinaten (poly, Anzahl):
        min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = poly.bounds
        while len(Punkte) < Anzahl:
            Zufallspunkt = Point([random.uniform(min_x, max_x), random.uniform(min_y, max_y)])
            if (Zufallspunkt.within(poly)):
                Punkte.append(Zufallspunkt)
        return Punkte
Punkte = Zufallskoordinaten(Alle_Polygone,3)
```

Unfortunately this results in this AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'bounds'.

Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Attribution matters - where did you find this code exactly?

Comment: I found the code on this website: https://medium.com/the-data-journal/a-quick-trick-to-create-random-lat-long-coordinates-in-python-within-a-defined-polygon-e8997f05123a
I found the code on this website: https://medium.com/the-data-journal/a-quick-trick-to-create-random-lat-long-coordinates-in-python-within-a-defined-polygon-e8997f05123a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the same StackExchange thread where you found your code, there exists a function `object.representative_point()`, which:

> Returns a cheaply computed point that is guaranteed to be within the
> geometric object.

Why reinvent the wheel? Whatever shapely has implemented behind the scenes is guaranteed to be much more efficient than endlessly looping until you happen to pick  n-points that satisfy your criteria.

```
def get_random_points(polygon, num_points):
    return [polygon.representative_point() for _ in range(num_points)]

def main():
    all_polygons = [...]
    all_points = []
    points_per_polygon = 3
    for polyon in all_polygons:
        all_points.append(get_random_points(polygon, points_per_polygon))
    print(all_points)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

- You loop over your polygons, but pass all polygons to the function, where it accepts a polygon, not a list of polygons. `Alle_Polygone` has no `.bounds`, as you get the error, but the elements within `Alle_Polygone`, i.e. the polygons, they have.
- It is enough to define the function once, not in the loop.
- Call the defined function inside the loop (remember, python is whitespace sensitive, tabs matter).

Store the returned points in a list (structured) if it is important which set of points corresponds to which polygon:

```py
alle_Punkte = []
def polygon_random_points (poly, Anzahl):
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = poly.bounds
    while len(Punkte) < Anzahl:
        Zufallspunkt = Point([random.uniform(min_x, max_x), random.uniform(min_y, max_y)])
        if (Zufallspunkt.within(poly)):
            Punkte.append(Zufallspunkt)
    return Punkte

for Standorte in Alle_Polygone:    
    Punkte = polygon_random_points(Standorte,3)
    alle_Punkte.append(Punkte)
```

Or if your intention was to define a function that accepts a set of polygons, then

```py
def Zufallskoordinaten (Alle_Polygone_, Anzahl):
    Punkte = []
    for Standorte in Alle_Polygone_:
        min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = Standorte.bounds
        i = 0  # number of points generated for this Standorte
        while i < Anzahl:
            Zufallspunkt = Point([random.uniform(min_x, max_x), random.uniform(min_y, max_y)])
            if (Zufallspunkt.within(Standorte)):
                Punkte.append(Zufallspunkt)
                i++
    return Punkte

alle_Punkte = Zufallskoordinaten (Alle_Polygone,3)
```

Both of these generate Anzahl number of points within each polygon. Is this what you want? Or a total of Anzahl points?

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. The first code is what I wanted.

Comment: You can also [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem.

Comment: I used the first code but I just realized that this code results in a repetition of the same 3 coordinates.

Comment: Then I tried the second code which you suggested but unfortunately I get an empty output with this one.

Comment: Sorry, it is a bit hard to test the a part of the code without having the full example. I corrected the first version, where the wrong function was called, not it is correctly `polygon_random_points`. In the second, I added the last line, that's how you should get all the points.